# Special characters throwing off str_pad in php?

Tags: php

I'm writing a module that is supposed to be able to export transaction records in BankOne format.

[Here is the specification of the format](https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod_object_assets/assets/1370813228725/CN_BankOneImport.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJJMCS3THBEIU2QRQ&Expires=1344470222&Signature=eu%2F6sb8Nl9vuveCvAn0arLQG49o%3D)

[Here is an example file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod_object_assets/assets/1370813228723/bankone.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJJMCS3THBEIU2QRQ&Expires=1344450213&Signature=ZxTODQq/1n220LDOZcFn6ZOgkBQ=)

The fields are put in specific ranges on the line and records are seperated by new lines. Lots of spaces needs to be added to ensure that the fields start and end at specific points in the line.

I wrote a function in php for this. It takes in the fields as parameters and should return a properly formatted record.

```
function record4($checknum='', $nameid='', $purpose='', $pledge='', $payment='', 
             $frequency='', $title='', $fname='', $lname='', $suffix='',
             $address='', $postalcode='', $city='', $state='', $greeting='')
{
$fields = array(
    'checknum' => array('length' => 8, 'start' => 37),
    'nameid' => array('length' => 7, 'start' => 45),
    'purpose' => array('length' => 5, 'start' => 52),
    'pledge' => array('length' => 10, 'start' => 57),
    'payment' => array('length' => 10, 'start' => 67),
    'frequency' => array('length' => 1, 'start' => 77),
    'title' => array('length' => 20, 'start' => 78),
    'fname' => array('length' => 40, 'start' => 98),
    'lname' => array('length' => 40, 'start' => 138),
    'suffix' => array('length' => 20, 'start' => 178),
    'address' => array('length' => 35, 'start' => 198),
    'postalcode' => array('length' => 10, 'start' => 233),
    'city' => array('length' => 28, 'start' => 243),
    'state' => array('length' => 5, 'start' => 271),
    'greeting' => array('length' => 40, 'start' => 276)
);

$str = '4';
foreach($fields as $field_name => $field)
{
    if($$field_name)
    {
        $str = str_pad($str, $field['start']-1, ' ');
        $str = $str.substr(trim((string)$$field_name), 0, $field['length']);
    }
}

return $str."\n";
}
```

It seems to work as intended, but when I looked at the output file I found this (scroll to the end):

```
4                                                                 1                              David                                   Landrum
4                                                                 3                              Hazel                                   Baker
4                                                                 3                              Jerome                                  Zehnder
4                                                                 1                              VÃ­ctor                               Nadales
4                                                                 2                              Philip                                  Nauert
4                                                                 1                              Jana                                    Ortcutter
```

The file contains 900 records pulled from a database, all of them are formatted correctly, except VÃ­ctor Nadales. After that first name, every other field is three spaces left of where it is supposed to be. The only anomalous thing about this record appears to be the 'Ã' in the first name.

The function is supposed to pad out the string to the proper length after each and every field it processes, yet it somehow gets fooled on this one line?

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

EDIT: I just realized that whatever imports files of this format might not even support special UTF-8 characters. Therefore I added this line to my code:

```
$$field_name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $$field_name);
```

The Ã comes out looking like this: ~A-. Not ideal, but at least the file is formatted properly now.

Comment: It's most likely a multibyte string issue (see the `mb_str*` functions).

Comment: My guess is that it's because `'Ã'` is four bytes long, and `str_pad` is counting bytes rather than logical characters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is happening because `'Ã'` is a multi-byte character (4 bytes long), and `str_pad` is counting bytes rather than logical characters.

This is why you are missing three spaces, `str_pad` is counting `'Ã'` as 4 single byte characters instead of one multi-byte one.

Try this function ([credit here](https://gist.github.com/226350)).

```
<?
function mb_str_pad( $input, $pad_length, $pad_string = ' ', $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT)
{
    $diff = strlen( $input ) - mb_strlen( $input );
    return str_pad( $input, $pad_length + $diff, $pad_string, $pad_type );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the function you gave me, however it seems to still be tripping up on the same line. I switched substr to mb_substr as well.

Comment: Hmm, odd. I haven't personally tested the function, but I thought that it would work. What is the output of `mb_strlen` vs. `strlen` on your unicode input string? Is it properly detecting the multi-byte character?

Comment: mb_strlen("VÃ­ctor") and strlen("VÃ­ctor") both return int(9) =/

Comment: apparently the encoding needs to be set. I tried passing in "UTF-8" (database uses utf8-general-ci) but it returns int(7) which is also incorrect. I guess it's just a matter of finding the right encoding...

Comment: Hmm, so then `mb_strlen` is not working correctly. Maybe try explicitly setting your encoding? The [reference page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) seems to have some info on how to do that.

Comment: Character encodings are the bane of my existence :). [Here's the list of all available encodings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) (although you've probably already found that, it was linked from the main reference page.)

Comment: There is a feature request in the PHP bug tracker for integrating such a function in the core. Please look at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21317 and **vote** for it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Using Gordon's solution you just have to add the encoding type to the `mb_strlen` and it will count the bytes correctly (at least it worked for me)

Here is the function I used:

```
function mb_str_pad( $input, $pad_length, $pad_string = ' ', $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT, $encoding="UTF-8") {
    $diff = strlen( $input ) - mb_strlen($input, $encoding);
    return str_pad( $input, $pad_length + $diff, $pad_string, $pad_type );
}
```

Credit for the idea [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#90611)

Answer (score 2):

```
function mb_str_pad($input, $pad_length, $pad_string = ' ', $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT) {
    $diff = strlen($input) - mb_strlen($input,mb_detect_encoding($input));
    return str_pad($input, $pad_length + $diff, $pad_string, $pad_type);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: it autodetects enconding of input string in the second param of mb_strlen by using mb_detect_encoding, so no need to add another param to the function call itself